Configure Squid to perform certification validation without decrypting the traffic
I am looking into using Squid as a forward proxy. My requirement is that the proxy should not decrypt the message (at least not entirely) but it should perform cert validation. My understanding is that it should be possible with SSL Bump and peek, however I can't make it work. Is it even possible to achieve what I want?
This is my current configuration:
# ACLs for SSL Bumping
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3

# Define SSL and Safe ports
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 443

# Allow specific methods and deny others
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

# Basic http_access controls
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Allow access from local network
http_access allow localhost

# Allowed sites
acl allowed_sites dstdomain .google.com

# Allow traffic to pass through Squid for allowed sites (after SSL validation)
http_access allow allowed_sites

# Deny all other access
http_access deny all

# Define HTTP and HTTPS ports
http_port 3128

# SSL Bump Configuration
# Step 1: Peek at the SNI to get the domain name
ssl_bump peek step1

# Step 2: Validate the certificate for allowed_sites
ssl_bump bump step2 allowed_sites

# Step 3: Splice the connection if the certificate is valid
ssl_bump splice step3 allowed_sites

# Terminate all other connections that fail certificate validation
ssl_bump terminate all

# SSL certificate error handling
sslproxy_cert_error deny all


I don't really have access to a squid server, but opening port 80 in the past has fixed issues. I would also make sure squid can accept the TLS protocol you need, assuming it's disabled by default. Don't quote me on it, but what you're looking to do is read the SNI header, which I'm not sure if Squid can do without decrypting traffic. You might take a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/1133064/transparent-https-proxy-with-squid-using-sni. Otherwise see if just splicing the traffic is possible. HAProxy should be able to achieve this without issue. You can always read TCP dump.
